# IIS Issue with CORs policy

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, axios, coldfusion, iis-10

I have a site running locally that is giving me the following error:
[image: error message]

I have the local site set up in the web.config file but I do not know whare the '*' is coming from.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>            
                <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{SCRIPT_NAME}" pattern="\.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js|txt|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|xml|cfc|cfm|html|flv|swf|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg|map|mpeg|mp4|avi|mov|wmv|zip)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect to CF Server" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^api/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is a Vue site running and trying to reach a Coldfusion API running locally as well.

My issue is I do not know where IIS is getting the '*' from in the CORS request.

I have tried manipulating the web.config file and if I take the

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000" />
```

out of the web.config then I cannot access the the local API site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

Comment: Perhaps you could try inspecting the network request and response using something like Fiddler or browser developer tools to see if you can confirm how the '*' is added to the header.

Comment: I got past the issue by installing a chrome extension "Requestly" which allowed me to modify the request headers. I found the solution in the link that Adrian provided.